# Search a string/value in huge dictionary in python efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, optimization, multiprocessing, hpc

Say I huge dict eg `huge_dict={'Key1': 'ABC' , 'Key 2' : 'DEF' ,'KEY 4' :'GHI', 'KEY5': 'IJK' ... , 'KEY N': 'XYZ'}`
It take lots of  time to search value in huge_dict I was trying  multiprocessing  technique as it uses diffrient cores
I am trying to do follwing Steps:
1: split  huge_dict in m small dict
2: create m process in python and  pass seraching value to it
3: if any of  process  get the  value then terminate  all processes.

prior to this  I load  Deep Learning / Machine  Learning  Model. when  try to use multiprocessing  it gets  loaded as mnay times as my prrocess are  spawn
whose output is huge_dict

```
 huge_dict = {'Key1': 'ABC' , 'Key 2' : 'DEF' ,'KEY 4' :'GHI', 'KEY5': 'IJK'}
 d1 = dict(huge_dict.items()[len(huge_dict)/2:])
 d2 = dict(huge_dict.items()[:len(huge_dict)/2])
# Is this an efficient  way to do it ? what if  I split in n dict 

def worker(dict , searck_value, num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print('Worker:', num)
    print(mp.cpu_count())
    return dict
#is is correct way to use multiprocessing

#current using  time consuming logic:
def search(d, word)
d = {'key1': "ASD", 'key2': "asd", 'key3':"fds", 'key4':"gfd", 'key5': "hjk"}
for key in d:
    if(d[key] in "search sentence or grp of words")#doing fuzzy search here
        return d[key]
```

The data format is as follows:

```
huge_dict={"10001": ["sentence1", "sentence2","sentence3","sentence4"],
       "4001": ["sentence1", "sentence2"], 
"35432": ["sentence1", "sentence2","sentence3","sentence4", ... "sentence N"],  
.....
"N":["N no of sentences"]    }
```

Comment: Isn't the purpose of a dictionary to be able to find a value based on its key?

Comment: can you add the exact code that takes a lot of time?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I agree but  after doing  some  processing;  I am getting dictionary in which  i need to find if the text i am seacrhing  for exit or not.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson isn't wrong. Sounds like you have your key/values backwards, and/or you're not using the right data structure for the job. What are you trying to do? Are you just trying to search whether or not the value is there? Or do you need to get that value's key? What's the goal?

Comment: @LanteDellarovere current logic i have  uppdated. But it take lots of time hence I am planning to use multi processing so i can utilise all CPU cores of server which are ideal as mutli threading in python doenot allow to use multiple cpu core also share the same data[huge dict]. i was initially planning multi processing only but I came to know thread use single core hence drop that plan

Comment: so you want to know if any of the `huge_dict` values is in a given string?

Comment: @MattMessersmith I am getting this output from some module [3rd party module]. I dont have any  means to change it actually {'key1': "ASD"} i just gave logical example but actually it a  array eg { "key1" : ["sentence 1", "sentence 2"] }  on top of it  i am using  fuzzy search kind of logic

Comment: @LanteDellarovere yes

Comment: But you don't care about the key...so why not beat the output `dict` into a different data structure that has the performance characteristics that you need? Might be smart to turn your values into a `set`, tokenize the sentence, then check if any of the tokens are in the `set`, and if so return the token (or sentence, whatever you care about). Still not totally clear what you're doing, but I can tell you that looping over the values of a dictionary is not algorithmically efficient. And no amount of CPU power will make up for a bad algorithm (example: bogo sort)

Comment: @MattMessersmith I tried set it doesnt  server the business logic/ functional  purpose as  I require the  key as  well

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to check if any of the `huge_dict` values is present as substring (not only word) in a given string.
Try if the `set.intersection` of `huge_dict.values()` and all substrings of the given string is faster:

```
def sub(s):
    """ Return all substrings of a given string """
    return [s[i:j+1] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i,len(s))]


huge_dict = {'Key1': 'ABC' , 'Key 2' : 'DEF' ,'KEY 4' :'GHI', 'KEY5': 'IJK'}
s = "A REKDEFY, CI"

huge_values = set(huge_dict.values())
>>> print(huge_values.intersection(sub(s))
{'DEF'}
```